# Why is my javascript module returning undefined when I try to access variables?

Tags: javascript, module, self-invoking-function

I have a javascript module that neatly separates data from dom and returns a public api for its `data` and `ui` objects:

```
var PtCalcApp = (function() {
    var ptCalc = ptCalc || {};

    ptCalc.ui = {
        storage: $('#pt-storage'),
        backup: {
            daily: $('#per-day-data'),
            weekly: $('#per-week-data'),
            monthly: $('#per-month-data'),
            yearly: $('#per-year-data')
        },
        change: {
            yearly: $('#annual-change'),
            daily: $('#daily-change')
        }
    };

    ptCalc.data = {
        storage: function() {
            ptCalc.ui.storage.val()
        }
    }

    return ptCalc;
})();
```

Now when I try to access data like this this:

```
PtCalcApp.data.storage()
```

it returns `undefined`. What am I doing wrong with this self invoking function pattern? How do I fix this?

Comment: You are storing the data directly in the DOM in visual format, I don't see the separation.

Comment: Ok can you show me a better way to do this without using a mvc framework?

Comment: This doesn't look like a valid selector `$('pt-storage')`

Comment: You are right - that fixed the ui access issue - but now I am still not getting my storage input data when I call `PtCalcApp.data.storage()` - I get `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning anything from the function. Without a `return` statement, the function will return `undefined` (unless called with `new`, but that's a different matter).

```
storage: function() {
    ptCalc.ui.storage.val()
}
```

should be

```
storage: function() {
    return ptCalc.ui.storage.val()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`PtCalcApp.ui.storage` is not a function, it is a property.

You need to access it using `PtCalcApp.ui.storage` not as `PtCalcApp.ui.storage()`

If you want to use a a function then you need to declare it as

```
storage: function(){
    return $('pt-storage');
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I made mistake in posting the code I was accessing it as `PtCalcApp.ui.storage` - It doesn't work

Comment: @AmitErandole looks like you are missing `#` in front of `pt-storage`

Comment: You are right - I fixed that but there is still the problem with not getting my data back